# Android: Fill array up to a certain length

Tags: android, indexoutofboundsexception, arrays

**The situation**

I have got different char[] arrays with a different amount of items. To avoid the "OutOfBounds"-Error while processing them I want to standardize them. 
For Example:

My Array has following items: "5;9" --> What I want it to look like: "0,0,0,0,5,9" (fill up with "0"s to 6 items)

**What I tried:**

```
char[] myarray1 = mystring1.toCharArray();
...
for(int i=0; i<6; i++){
        myarray1[i] = 0;
        if(i<myarray1.length-1){
            myarray1[i] = myarray1[i];
        }else{
            myarray1[i] = 0;
        };
    };
```

My code failed, because it evokes exactly that error...

I hope somebody can help me :) 
Thanks!

Comment: Are you only working with numbers?  If so, why are you working with a String?  Are you taking the String as an input, and you just have to match the formatting to produce an output of six characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why your solution doesn't work is that you are using the same array for everything.
After `char[] myarray1 = mystring1.toCharArray();` the length of `myarray1` is 2, so you cannot simply assign entry 2,3,4 and 5 in your loop. Furthermore if you want the character ´0´ to be in the string, you need to surround your zeros with apostrophes.

You can fix your solution like this:

```
char[] myNewArray = new char[6];
int myarrayIndex = 0;
for(int i=0; i<6; i++)
{
    if(i < (myNewArray.length - myarray1.length)) {
        myNewArray[i] = '0';
    } else {
        myNewArray[i] = myarray1[myarrayIndex++];
    };
};

System.out.println(myNewArray); //Will print out: 000059
```

An easier solution could be this:

```
myarray1 = String.format("%6s", mystring1).replace(' ', '0').toCharArray();
```

Comment: Thanks! Second solutions works great and is sooooo simple :) I didn't think of String.format... anyways, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Firstly trying to fill 0's is not going to fix the error.
Secondly your logic is not right(assuming size as 6), change it to `myString.length()`. 
And I don't understand the point of `myarray1[i] = myarray1[i];`.

Anyways, every array with integer size is initialized by Zero's according to [Java specs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/#4.12.5). On the other hand if you want to fill it with any other value, try [Arrays.fill()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#fill%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29).

Answer (score 0):

I think this function will accomplish what you're trying to do.

```
private static String formatString(String input)
{
    String FORMATTED_STRING = "0,0,0,0,0,0";
    int difference = FORMATTED_STRING.length() - input.length();
    return FORMATTED_STRING.substring(0, difference) + input;
}
```